# displaying html page through apache

Tags: apache2

i am using ubuntu and i have a html page named first.html at home/sanu directory and i have apache2 installed and running.i want host this page through apache from my pc how can i do that. (My pc's IP is :218.248.80.51) .i have tried to access "http://218.248.80.51/sanu/first.html" but its not working(Google Chrome could not connect to 218.248.80.51) in my browser.plz help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default Apache points to /var/www on ubuntu, it would required extra configuration to get it to point at your home directory. Try moving your html file there, then you should be able to access it through your browser at http://localhost/first.html

To host the page for public viewing you'd need to configure your pc's & router's firewalls correctly to allow port 80.